# That clause after a sentence

Tags: definite-article

How it is said the below sentence or is it correct as written?

> Bring the book to my office that I gave you last month.

Is anyone can explain in details?

Answer (score 1):

> that I gave you last month

is [**a relative clause**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#English) that modifies the noun "book".

According to the Wikipedia: *In English, a relative clause **follows** the noun it modifies.*

Let's just reorder the sentence a bit

> Bring the book **that I gave you last month** to my office.